# Squash commits into one commit

Tags: git

I want to squash commiets into one commit. Here is the example.

```
git log --pretty=oneline

c4101e...  removed conflict
04830f...  T2345 - [Bug fix1] 
16d19f...  T2272 - [Bug fix2]
```

My requirement is,
he code changes done in **c4101e** (latest commit) and **16d19f** (3rd commit) treated as one. like this

```
c4101e...  removed conflict and T2272 - [Bug fix2]
04830f...  T2345 - [Bug fix1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git rebase for that. git rebase -i HEAD~3 and ignore the commit in the middle.

Check http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase and `git rebase -i`

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase -i HEAD~3` for interactive rebasing of last 3 commits. It will open text editor with one line for each commit. You can then reorder them as you want and change `pick` command to `squash` for squashing commit to previous one.

When you open file, it will look something like:

```
pick c4101e...  removed conflict
pick 04830f...  T2345 - [Bug fix1] 
pick 16d19f...  T2272 - [Bug fix2]
```

Change it to:

```
pick c4101e...  removed conflict
squash 16d19f...  T2272 - [Bug fix2]
pick 04830f...  T2345 - [Bug fix1]
```

This will open extra text editor for editing commit message of squashed commit. If you just want to use commit message of first commit, use `fixup` instead of `squash`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in above case is

git reset HEAD~3

git add

git commit

Comment: Don't use that! If you've changed same files in ```Bug fix1``` and ```Bug fix2``` commits, there is no way to separate those changes again.